# Как можно сделать такой RadioButton?

Tags: android, xml

[image]

Мне нужно сделать такие `RadioButton` и добавить их в `RadioGroup`. Возможно ли создать свой кастомный `radiobutton` со своей разметкой?

Answer (score 2):

Создаёте в `res\drawable` примерно такое

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rbutton_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rbutton_unchecked" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

назовём его `rbutton_selector.xml` например, и добавляете его к вашему `RadioButton` в основной разметке

```
<RadioButton
 ...
 android:button="@drawable/rbutton_selector"
/>
```

остаётся только создать `drawable/rbutton_checked` и `drawable/rbutton_unchecked` для выбранного и невыбранного состояния.

А что касается именно того варианта, который вам нужен, то могу предложить примерно такое:

```
<RadioGroup
    ...
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/<ваша картинка>" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
                    android:text="Radio Button Text" />
            </LinearLayout>
    ...
    </RadioGroup>
```

ну и придётся добавить свою логику в совместную работу переключателей, ибо `RadioButton` уже не является наследником `RadioGroup` и единичный выбор делаться не будет.

Comment: android:background="@drawable/rbutton_selector" наверное, нет?

Comment: можно и так, тогда надо указать `android:button="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: не совсем то что надо получается, если сделать `android:button="@drawable/rbutton_selector"` то пропадают сами круги `radiobutton`

Comment: Добавил вариант в ответ